# django channels can not output logs in real time

Tags: django-channels

my code:

```
def ws_receive(message):
    text = message.content['text']
    request = json.loads(text)
    cmd = request['cmd']      

    results = run(cmd)
    print(cmd)
    for result in results:
         Group(GROUP_NAME).send({'text':result.decode('utf-8')})
         print(result)
```

`cmd` is like `ping -c 4 www.google.com`;

the terminal results is:

```
[2017/09/24 07:24:44] WebSocket HANDSHAKING / [127.0.0.1:59285]
[2017/09/24 07:24:44] WebSocket CONNECT / [127.0.0.1:59285]
[2017/09/24 07:24:44] HTTP GET /api/hosts/?status=used 200 [0.07, 127.0.0.1:59247]
ping -c 4 www.google.com
2017-09-24 07:24:58.512885 b'PING www.google.com (74.125.23.103): 56 data bytes\n'
2017-09-24 07:24:58.513127 b'64 bytes from 74.125.23.103: icmp_seq=0 ttl=45 time=138.542 ms\n'
2017-09-24 07:24:59.517881 b'64 bytes from 74.125.23.103: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=142.954 ms\n'
2017-09-24 07:25:00.522698 b'64 bytes from 74.125.23.103: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=144.568 ms\n'
2017-09-24 07:25:01.562285 b'64 bytes from 74.125.23.103: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=180.163 ms\n'
2017-09-24 07:25:01.562400 b'\n'
2017-09-24 07:25:01.562459 b'--- www.google.com ping statistics ---\n'
2017-09-24 07:25:01.562517 b'4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss\n'
2017-09-24 07:25:01.562586 b'round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 138.542/151.557/180.163/16.662 ms\n'
```

but,The browser's websocket debugging information is:
[image: browser ws debug]

so, I‘am sure the channels is execute the command until the end sent the message,but i want real-time send the message.

Comment: I want to print logs in real time to the browser, use `ping` or `tail -f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending immediately:

```py
Group(GROUP_NAME).send({'text':result.decode('utf-8')}, immediately=True)
```

The reason behind this is that you are inside the websocket consumer function. While you are inside it, the `Group.send` calls are not executed, but only collected and executed in batch once you leave the function. Using  `immediately=True` overrides this behaviour.